# Ratchet modal don't appear with Meteor

Tags: mobile, meteor, hybrid-mobile-app, ratchet

I've install Ratchet package from Atpmosphere. 
CSS work fine, but some script not. For example, Modal. I try to invoke it simply by adding the example code from [Ratchet website](http://goratchet.com/components/#modals) to test:

```
    <a href="#myModalexample" class="btn">Open modal</a>
<div id="myModalexample" class="modal">
  <header class="bar bar-nav">
    <a class="icon icon-close pull-right" href="#myModalexample"></a>
    <h1 class="title">Modal</h1>
  </header>

  <div class="content">
    <p class="content-padded">The contents of my modal go here. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

but nothing appear. No errors appear in the JS console. 
How can I use Ratchet Modal in Meteor? Which kind of Meteor mobile UI framework you suggest me to prevent this error (if Ratchet is bad to use)?
Thanks!

Comment: I've got the exact same problem here, did you find a way to make it work ? Thanks

Comment: Any solution to the modal issue?